# Anylogic - restrict agents from going into specific GIS region

Tags: anylogic

I'm currently working on a model where agents move to random points in the ocean on a GIS map. However, I want them to path in such a way that they do not collide with any islands on the map. I was thinking about creating GIS regions using the perimeter of the islands and was hoping there was some access restriction option for GIS regions. However, this does not seem to be a feature yet.

Does anyone have any tips on how to make agents avoid entering certain regions while moving towards a point on a GIS map? Thanks.

Comment: in order to do that, you need to have your own routing system probably with GISRoutes i think thats the only way, at least having GISregions defined in anylogic

Answer (score 0):

Create GISRoutes and move along those

Comment: Got it - I was thinking along those lines, but given that the target locations are random, it doesn't seem very elegant to define routes for every possible target "spawn" point on the GIS map. Is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to generate the routes and then assess if they do overlap an island. If they do then you change that part of the route. See code example below, note I did not do all the math to create a new route that goes around the island... You believe you can do this yourself. It is going to be a piece of work, so I did not test this or develop the completed solution.

```
GISRoute route = main.map.getRoute(currentLat, currentLong, toLat, toLong);

List<GISMarkupSegment> segementsToKeep = new ArrayList<GISMarkupSegment>()

SegmentForLoop:
for (int i = 0; i < route.getSegmentCount(); i++) {
    GISMarkupSegment segment = route.getSegment(i);
    // Check if the segmeent is too close to an island, if within 100m then we adjust the segment and stop adding segeents
    for (Pair<Double, Double> pair:main.LatLongPointsOIfIslands) {
        double distance = Math.sqrt(segment.getDistanceSq(new Point(pair.getFirst(), pair.getSecond())));
        if (distance < 100) {
            segment.setEnd(pair.getFirst() + 100, pair.getSecond()+100);
            break SegmentForLoop:
        }
        segementsToKeep.add(segment);
    }   
}

GISRoute routeUpToIsland = new GISRoute(main, segementsToKeep);

//TODO
// Create a new route around the island
// Add the segements of this new route to segementsToKeep
```

LatLongPointsOIfIslands is a collection of Pair<Double,Double> which is just lat and long combinations of all the GIS points of the island perimeters

I hope this helps or puts you on the right direction.

Alterantively you can investigate alternative routing providers

[image]